# Ajax call not performing well

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

I am trying to send mail with ajax through handler. and I have no idea why..

can someone direct me to an article or other that explaining how to "investigate" ajax calls?

Project->App_Code->Mail.cs (Send the mail)

```
  public static bool SendMail(string email)
    {
        DatingUser du = BL.BlContent.GetUser_ByEmail(email);
        if (du != null) 
        {//  Email sending
            string thePassword = du.Password;
        string eBody = "<div style='direction:rtl;'><b>your password is:  </b>" +thePassword;
        MailMessage MyMailMessage = new MailMessage("XXX@gmail.com", "XXX@gmail.com", "message", eBody);
              MyMailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;
              try
              {
                  SmtpClient SMTPServer = new SmtpClient();
                  SMTPServer.Send(MyMailMessage);
                  return true;
              }
              catch
              {
                  return false;
              }


        }
        return false;
    }
```

project->Handlers->forgotPass_sendMail.ashx

```
   public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        String emailToSendTo = context.Request.Form.Get("email");
        bool mailSent = Mail.SendMail(emailToSendTo);

        if (mailSent)
        {            
            context.Response.Write("true");
        }
        else
        {
            context.Response.Write("false");
        }
    }
```

project->controls->LogIn.ascx

```
 <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btn_forgotPass" Text="send" ValidationGroup="forgot" OnClientClick="EmailForgotPass(); " />
 function EmailForgotPass() {
    var settings = {
        'data': $('#email_forgotPass').val(),
        'url': "~/Handlers/forgotPass_sendMail.ashx",
        'contentType': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'
    };
    SendMail(settings);
}

function SendMail(settings) {
    var success = false;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: settings.contentType,
        data: settings.url,
        dataType: "json",
        async: true,
        success: function (data) {
            success = true;
            $('#mailStatus').html('<p>Your password has been sent</p>');
        },
        error: function (data) {              
            success = false;
            $('#mailStatus').html('<p>Something wen\'t wrong</p>');
        }
    });
    return false;
```

What am I doing wrong? 
any advise will be appreciated as well as an article on "how to explore ajax errors"

Comment: what is your specific question?

Comment: well you should put your setting.url inside url not data, and put the variables you want to pass to the next page in data.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your error block

```
error: function (data) {    
        alert(data);          
        success = false;
        $('#mailStatus').html('<p>Something wen\'t wrong</p>');
    }
```

This will give you a message box with an error if the server is returning an error. Otherwise you could use a browser like Chrome which has Developer Tools and you can view the request and response data associated with your ajax call.

Comment: already tried that, the alert box contains "Object object"
I am using chrome, don't you know any article that explain how view the requests and the responses

Answer (score 0):

URL line was wrong I think

```
$.ajax(
{
    type: "POST",
    contentType: settings.contentType,
    data: settings.data,//I changed this line of code <------------
    url: settings.url,//And this one <----------------------
    dataType: "json",
    async: true,
    success: function (data) {
        success = true;
        $('#mailStatus').html('<p>Your password has been sent</p>');
    },
    error: function (data) {              
        success = false;
        $('#mailStatus').html('<p>Something wen\'t wrong</p>');
    }
```

You can check your PHP_error.log file on the server.  This will give you the error message.(By default it is inside c:\Windows\Temp on IIS on Linux I couldn't tell)

you also have some more line of code wrong like this one :

```
String emailToSendTo = context.Request.Form.Get("email");
//your doing a POST request not a GET
```

maybe it should be something like:

```
String emailToSendTo = context.Request.Form.Post("email");
```

The only other thing I-dont-like/Not-sure-of is the

```
public void ProcessRequest(...)
```

I dont think this is how you send an AJAX request througth ASP.Net. What I mean is I dont think this function is even called when this page load.

Comment: Check the url line inside the AJAX POST request

Comment: checked it in the developer tools in chrome: "~/Handlers/forgotPass_sendMail.ashx:" Looks OK not?

Comment: yup but that url should `url:settings.url` not `data:settings.url`

Comment: you right, but it didn't solve it.. I added this:
 data: settings.data, url: settings.url

Comment: find what was wrong:
1) $('#email_forgotPass') <- forgot to add clientIdMode="static"
2) 'url': "~/Handlers/.... <- ~is not directing to the right place cause its a user control, I needed to just use "Handlers/...."

But all of that was guesses.. there isn't some article about this type of things?

Comment: I am guessing MSDN doc would help you out on this or even google